# Rename Pandas dataframe with NaN header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header

i currently work with dataframes, and i'm stacking them thus to achieve specific format. I have a question i'm trying to change name of the header but it doesn't work ( by using.. .rename(columns={'NaN'='type', inplace=True), same thing im trying to change the name of columns '6' to Another with the same principe as mentioned.

Here:

```
                                               NaN Quantity
6                                                                 
01/06                       KULUTUS - CONSUMPTION  8976.27     
01/06  TEOLLISUUSKULUTUS - INDUSTRIAL CONSUMPTION  4121.36    
01/06             MUU KULUTUS - OTHER CONSUMPTION  4854.91
```

Answer (score 18):

I think you need `rename` by `dict` or [`Index.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.fillna.html):

```
df = df.rename(columns={np.nan: 'type'})
```

---

```
df.columns = df.columns.fillna('type')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,4]], columns=[np.nan, 'a'])
print (df)
   NaN  a
0    1  4

print (df.columns.tolist())
[nan, 'a']

df1 = df.rename(columns={np.nan: 'type'})
print (df1)
   type  a
0     1  4
```

---

```
df.columns = df.columns.fillna('type')
print (df)
   type  a
0     1  4
```

Comment: In pandas 0.23 the first approach did not work for renaming an index value, however the second approach did.  Still curious about how to get the first approach to work.

Comment: @Selah the pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html) gets to the crux of this issue. 
`In [12]: np.nan == np.nan` 
`Out[12]: False`
To paraphrase, np.nan != np.nan and therefore the dictionary lookup doesn't work. That said, the test examples above work for me, however the method doesn't work in my real life pd.DataFrame. @tozCSS solution did work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Directly applying `.rename` still not working in pandas version `0.24.2` as well when `nan` is in the labels, looks like a bug to me. Note: this label is created by another pandas method in the first place: `pd.get_dummies(s,dummy_na=True)`.

My workaround is to convert the column labels to `str` first:
`df.rename(columns=str).rename(columns={'nan':'new_lbl'})`

Comment: Thanks for this. A minor edit which I think may apply to others, I am using pandas version `1.2.3` and  `df.rename(columns=str)` evaluates the NaN column to 'None'. Therefore, for me, the line is: 
`df.rename(columns=str).rename(columns={'None':'new_lbl'})`

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas version `0.25.3` with a `nan` value in the index, calling `df.rename(index={np.nan: 'new_label'})` is not working for me either.

Following tozCSS's suggestion, renaming all index labels to string (albeit all others besides that one were...) and then renaming worked for me:

```py
df.rename(index=str).rename(columns={'nan':'new_lbl'})
```

Link to documentation: [pandas.DataFrame.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)